# Getting 'Null Reference' error while working with Array in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`Unity 2022.3.9f1 LTS`

So basically I have a Inventory Object which has 'InventoryManager' attached to it, and same class has the Array of 'InventorySlot' with Lenght 10.

I am using the following method for swapping/moving item in the inventory Array :

```
    public class ItemSlot
    {
        [SerializeField] public string ItemName;
        [SerializeField] public ItemsSO ItemProperty;
        [SerializeField] public int ItemAmount;
    }

    [SerializeField] public ItemSlot[] playerInventory;
    private void Start()
    {
        playerInventory = new ItemSlot[10];
    }

    public void MoveItemInPlayerInventoryFromPlayerInventory(ItemSlot movingItem, int inventoryIndex)
    {
        int movingItemIndex = Array.IndexOf(playerInventory, movingItem);

        Debug.LogError($"Item Drag At Inventory Index : {inventoryIndex} \nItem Checking : !{playerInventory[inventoryIndex].ItemName}! ");

        // Destination slot is empty
        if (playerInventory[inventoryIndex].ItemProperty == null)
        {
            playerInventory[inventoryIndex] = playerInventory[movingItemIndex];
            playerInventory[movingItemIndex] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            // Swap items
            ItemSlot temp = playerInventory[inventoryIndex];
            playerInventory[inventoryIndex] = playerInventory[movingItemIndex];
            playerInventory[movingItemIndex] = temp;
        }

        InventoryUIManager.Instance.ShowItemPreviewAtInventory();
    }
```

Weird problem is - If I select the the Inventory Gameobject at the Hierarchy in the Play Mode, then this method is running perfect without any errors.

But If, I deselect the Inventory object and start playing the Game, then everytime I call the method, it is throwing 'null Reference' errors at line of '`Debug.LogError() & if (playerInventory[inventoryIndex].ItemProperty == null)`'.

I am attaching the Video link for the same - [Drive Link for the video of the Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EHVnWnhyRpShSy60cl3b7ZW50v-QUNnX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: well you potentially set items to `null` in `playerInventory[movingItemIndex] = null;` so at any point I guess the `playerInventory[inventoryIndex]` might be `null` when you try to access `playerInventory[inventoryIndex].ItemProperty` ...

Answer (score 1):

So it's hard to tell what's going on based on the video and context, but what I think is going on is that at the start of the game, you are initializing your inventory to  `playerInventory = new ItemSlot[10];` this means that you are creating an array with 10 elements of type `ItemSlot` but you haven't actually put anything inside those containers, so even if the compiler lets you look for a property of those type you need to check if there something in that container first so instead of doing the following:

```
        // Destination slot is empty
        if (playerInventory[inventoryIndex].ItemProperty == null)
        {
            playerInventory[inventoryIndex] = playerInventory[movingItemIndex];
            playerInventory[movingItemIndex] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            // Swap items
            ItemSlot temp = playerInventory[inventoryIndex];
            playerInventory[inventoryIndex] = playerInventory[movingItemIndex];
            playerInventory[movingItemIndex] = temp;
        }
```

you need to check first if the object is null

```
        // Destination slot is empty
        if (playerInventory[inventoryIndex] == null || playerInventory[inventoryIndex].ItemProperty == null)
        {
            playerInventory[inventoryIndex] = playerInventory[movingItemIndex];
            playerInventory[movingItemIndex] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            // Swap items
            ItemSlot temp = playerInventory[inventoryIndex];
            playerInventory[inventoryIndex] = playerInventory[movingItemIndex];
            playerInventory[movingItemIndex] = temp;
        }
```

That's my guess based on the context.